# Google Spreadsheet Autoincrement date value, does not work

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script to autoincrement a date value. I would like to increment one day at a time, but can't seem to get it to work, can anyone help me out?

This is the code so far:

```
function datum(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master');
    var getDatum = sheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
    var date = new Date(getDatum); // MM/DD/YYYY
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
    var dateStr = date.getDay()+'/'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getFullYear();
    var setDatum = sheet.getRange("W3");
    setDatum.clear();
    setDatum.setValue(dateStr);
}
```

If the value in the cell is 2/28/2017, I should get output 3/1/2017! Instead I get output of 3/3/2017.

Answer (score 0):

So yeah I solved it, this bit of code works:

```
function datum(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  var getDatum = sheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var date = new Date(getDatum);
  date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
  var setDatum = sheet.getRange("W3");
  setDatum.clear();
  setDatum.setValue(date);


}
```

Hope it helps someone!